# Skip row in a collection of BluePrism in case of exception

Tags: exception, collections, blueprism

In the project I'm developing for the client, if I find a particular condition for an item in the collection, the client told me to pass to the next line of the collection and report the exception.
How is it possible to pass over to next line in case of an exception in the handling of an item?

I except BluePrism passing to the next row of the collection.

Comment: Just as a side note, it doesn't seem to me that you can think in a programmatic way if you are asking a question like that. Are you really sure you are ok with building bots? I'm concerned because someone else will have to debug your bot when things start to fall apart and you might not be happy with what you are doing yourself, with that kind of time pressure and expectations on you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using Loop stage to go through collection. If so you need to use decision stage to find exception and then when condition is true you report it (in a form you agree with the customer) and then you just simply link it to the Loop End stage, if exception condition is not met you follow regular process logic.

If you are not using Loop stage, you should consider it. It allows you to easily iterate through collection rows. It consists of 2 blocks: Loop Start & Loop End. When your flow reaches the Loop End it will come back to the Start and increment the row count.